# Dynamic vertical to horizontal list in excel (using Index, aggregate, etc)

Tags: vba, excel

Ok, hopefully my question makes sense as I've been having bad rep of late. I've searched for the answer for a while now but can't find anything so I think I'm safe to ask the question haha.

I'm trying to dynamically list a bunch of rows from one table, to columns horizontally in another table. I think my issue might be a circular reference but I really can't work it out.

1. `=INDEX(mindbld[ID], AGGREGATE(15, 6, (ROW(mindbld[Type Auto])-ROW(mindbld[#Headers]))/(LEFT(mindbld[Type Auto], LEN($A$2))=$A$2), ROW(1:1)))`

This is the formula I'm using in my **OCCOUT** table. This dynamically lists a bunch of IDs vertically in column B from **MINDBLD** table. **Cell A2 contains my criteria** for this list: e.g. Office (ids). This works perfectly and is a pretty sweet formula.

2. `=INDEX(tblOCC[[Ten Sched]:[Ten Sched]], AGGREGATE(15, 6, (ROW(tblOCC[[Tenant ID]:[Tenant ID]])-ROW(tblOCC[#Headers]))/(LEFT(tblOCC[[Building ID]:[Building ID]], LEN(occout[@[ID2]:[ID2]]))=occout[@[ID2]:[ID2]]), COLUMN(E:E)))`

With this formula I'm trying to list the rows from **TBLOCC** horizontally. The table has a numerous rows that have information, with the same IDs as found in MINDBLD.

**Ten Sched** column in **TBLOCC** has the information I'm retrieving. **Tenant ID** is the furthest to the left column in TBLOCC. **Building ID** contains the same ID as found in **minbld[ID]**.

**OCCOUT ID2** contains the IDs found by **Formula 1** albeit in Column C (e.g. cell C2 =B2) as I thought this might be an issue.

The formula returns a **#NUM!** and I can't seem to fix it. Hopefully I've made myself clear. I have the feeling this would be much easier with VBA! (Which I don't know).

**EDIT #1**

Something interesting I've found, formula is in cell E2:

```
=INDEX(tblOCC[[Ten Sched]:[Ten Sched]], AGGREGATE(15, 6, (ROW(tblOCC[[Tenant ID]:[Tenant ID]])-ROW(tblOCC[#Headers]))/(LEFT(tblOCC[[B ID2]:[B ID2]], LEN($C1))=$C1), COLUMN(E:E)))
```

This works (referencing an ID above).

However if it references C2 in the same row as the formula it returns an error.

Comment: Have you tried puling out the individual pieces into separate formulas for debugging - they another cell with `occout[@[ID2]:[ID2]]` and another with `LEFT(tblOCC[[Building ID]:[Building ID]], LEN(occout[@[ID2]:[ID2]]))` - those look like they have the most potential for problems

Comment: @dbmitch Haven't done that yet - I'll give it a go now.

Comment: @dbmitch I think they're right - [abc]:[abc] is just an exact reference in a table.